# Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in /home/alabbrkq/public_html/system/database/DB_query_builder.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 public function count_all_results($table = '', $reset = TRUE)
{
    if ($table !== '')
    {
        $this->_track_aliases($table);
        $this->from($table);
    }

    $result = ($this->qb_distinct === TRUE)
        ? $this->query($this->_count_string.$this->protect_identifiers('numrows')."\nFROM (\n".$this->_compile_select()."\n) CI_count_all_results")
        : $this->query($this->_compile_select($this->_count_string.$this->protect_identifiers('numrows')));

    if ($reset === TRUE)
    {
        $this->_reset_select();
    }

    if ($result->num_rows() === 0) // this is the line with the issue
    {
        return 0;
    }

    $row = $result->row();
    return (int) $row->numrows;
}
```

Codeigniter
Customers are complaining about the checkout on my site having issues submitting their order. When i check the error log, this is the error i see. How can i fix this

Below areas of the controller with the string **count_all_results**

```
 $this->db->where('status','ok');
        $this->db->where('featured','ok');
        $this->db->where('added_by',json_encode(array('type'=>'vendor','id'=>$vendor_id)));
        // pagination
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('product');
        $config['base_url']   = base_url() . 'index.php?home/listed/';
        $config['per_page'] = 9;
        $config['uri_segment']  = 5;
        $config['cur_page_giv'] = $para2;
```

{
        $this->load->library('Ajax_pagination');

```
    $id= $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $this->db->where('from_where','{"type":"user","id":"'.$id.'"}');
    $this->db->or_where('to_where','{"type":"user","id":"'.$id.'"}');
    $config['total_rows']   = $this->db->count_all_results('ticket');
    $config['base_url']     = base_url() . 'index.php/home/ticket_listed/';
    $config['per_page']     = 5;
    $config['uri_segment']  = 5;
    $config['cur_page_giv'] = $para2;
```

{
        $this->load->library('Ajax_pagination');

```
    $id= $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $this->db->where('buyer', $id);
    $config['total_rows']   = $this->db->count_all_results('sale');
    $config['base_url']     = base_url() . 'index.php/home/order_listed/';
    $config['per_page']     = 5;
    $config['uri_segment']  = 5;
    $config['cur_page_giv'] = $para2;

    $function                  = "order_listed('0')";
    $config['first_link']      = '&laquo;';
    $config['first_tag_open']  = '<li><a rel="grow" class="btn-u btn-u-sea grow" onClick="' . $function . '">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $rr                       = ($config['total_rows'] - 1) / $config['per_page'];
    $last_start               = floor($rr) * $config['per_page'];
    $function                 = "order_listed('" . $last_start . "')";
    $config['last_link']      = '&raquo;';
    $config['last_tag_open']  = '<li><a rel="grow" class="btn-u btn-u-sea grow" onClick="' . $function . '">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $function                 = "order_listed('" . ($para2 - $config['per_page']) . "')";
    $config['prev_tag_open']  = '<li><a rel="grow" class="btn-u btn-u-sea grow" onClick="' . $function . '">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $function                 = "order_listed('" . ($para2 + $config['per_page']) . "')";
    $config['next_link']      = '&rsaquo;';
    $config['next_tag_open']  = '<li><a rel="grow" class="btn-u btn-u-sea grow" onClick="' . $function . '">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $config['full_tag_open']  = '<ul class="pagination pagination-style-2 pagination-sm">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

    $config['cur_tag_open']  = '<li class="active"><a rel="grow" class="btn-u btn-u-red grow" class="active">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $function                = "order_listed(((this.innerHTML-1)*" . $config['per_page'] . "))";
    $config['num_tag_open']  = '<li><a rel="grow" class="btn-u btn-u-sea grow" onClick="' . $function . '">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);
    $this->db->where('buyer', $id);
    $page_data['orders'] = $this->db->get('sale', $config['per_page'], $para2)->result_array();
    $this->load->view('front/user/order_listed',$page_data);
}
```

{
        $this->load->library('Ajax_pagination');

```
    $id= $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $ids = json_decode($this->db->get_where('user',array('user_id'=>$id))->row()->wishlist,true);
    $this->db->where_in('product_id', $ids);

    $config['total_rows']   = $this->db->count_all_results('product');;
    $config['base_url']     = base_url() . 'index.php/home/wish_listed/';
    $config['per_page']     = 5;
    $config['uri_segment']  = 5;
    $config['cur_page_giv'] = $para2;

    $function                  = "wish_listed('0')";
    $config['first_link']      = '&laquo;';
    $config['first_tag_open']  = '<li><a rel="grow" class="btn-u btn-u-sea grow" onClick="' . $function . '">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $rr                       = ($config['total_rows'] - 1) / $config['per_page'];
    $last_start               = floor($rr) * $config['per_page'];
    $function                 = "wish_listed('" . $last_start . "')";
    $config['last_link']      = '&raquo;';
    $config['last_tag_open']  = '<li><a rel="grow" class="btn-u btn-u-sea grow" onClick="' . $function . '">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
```

I have added areas of the controller that contain the string count_all_results i hope this helps

Comment: `num_rows()` that isn't a function in mysqli_. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php --- Unless you have a custom method of your own, which is unknown.

Comment: Your query failed. Why? Who knows. Try outputting the query to find out exactly what it looks like and run it manually in your database.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so how should i fix it, i did not write the code. the developer has very bad support. reported the issues 7 days ago

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's [part of CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html).

Comment: @aynber i would like to do that but i have no idea how. Can you create steps i can follow. Im hosting on cpanel

Comment: Nope, sorry, I haven't messed with CI in years. I know there's a logging function, but you might have to look at the documentation to find out how to use it.

Comment: @aynber *My bad*. Well, he can look through and use CI's error handling https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html if he's not already doing that.

Comment: show us the code where you are using the count_all_results() method. This is just a copy from the query builder (or active record in older versions which I think this is CI2)

Comment: The problem is NOT in the code you show. Do not mess with that code it is part of framework's (Codeigniter) core. The problem is likely in some "model" or "controller" in the site's code. Find the controller that handles posting of the order form. Show us that and we might be able to spot the problem.

Comment: @qweertzman i added the controller iwanted to ass th entire code but it was too long

Comment: @DFriend add the parts of the controller

Comment: Thanks for adding that code. It is still hard to know exactly which of those snippets is involved with handling the order form. `count_all_results` could fail if one of the calls to `$this->db->where(...` is given bad argument(s) or if one of the tables is missing. Though a missing table would probably show up in the error log too. Are there other entries in the log before the one in your heading?

Answer (score 0):

```
var = (condition x) ? y : z;
condition ? true : false;
```

in here where we have true "Y" and false "Z" is declared to var depending on condition. in your question the errors says operation is performed on `Boolean` which means the Y or Z is returning `Boolean` instead of value.

Please check the value declared by Y or Z and print them for batter debugging, there must be error in method you are calling or that method is returning `Boolean` instead of `Database Object` which is required for Code-igniter database library to perform operations.

Please edit your question and provide your code of methods for batter and accurate answer to your question.